# How do I make veriable name a .xls filename

Tags: matlab

I have a variable call `req = 'text'` & I am outputting a file as `MyFile = 'FileName.xls'`. I would like to output a file that contain whatever name req variable hold. From the above example, my output should be text.xls. I tried `MyFile = req,'.xls'` but this gets me .txt file? is there any way I cam do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `MyFile = req.'.xls'` you basically have two commands, the first `MyFile = req` creates the variable `MyFile` without extension and the second which is a char constant which does nothing. Use `[]` to concatenate chars:

```
MyFile = [req,'.xls']
```